# How to change UVMap index?

Tags: python

I need to change indexes for UVMaps. 
Here the screenshot:

[image]

I tried like this, according to ths page https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2493920/how-to-switch-position-of-two-items-in-a-python-list :

```
import bpy

cubeObject = bpy.context.scene.objects[0]
cubeObject.data.uv_textures[0], cubeObject.data.uv_textures[1] = cubeObject.data.uv_textures[1], cubeObject.data.uv_textures[0]
```

But I got this Exception:

```
read blend: /home/mifth/Desktop/2223/uvs.blend
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/mifth/Desktop/2223/uvs.blend/Text", line 4, in <module>
IndexError: bpy_prop_collection[index] = value: failed assignment (unknown reason)
```

This is very important for exporting models to game engines like Unity, Unreal, jMonkey, Ogre3D...

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [the blender 2.69 python API reference](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_69_release), `uv_textures` is a `bpy_prop_collection` of `MeshTexturePolyLayer` and it is read only. It would appear to be accessed in Python as a dictionary of key/value pairs (try `bpy.context.active_object.data.uv_textures.items()` in Blender's Python console). This would be why the array re-ordering techniques fail to work.

I'm not sure that this is the best way but it appears to work. Test to see if it fixes the export order.

```
import bpy

mesh = bpy.context.active_object.data

mesh.uv_textures.active_index = 0
tmpuvmap = mesh.uv_textures.active
tmpuvmap_name = tmpuvmap.name

newuvmap = mesh.uv_textures.new()
mesh.uv_textures.remove(tmpuvmap)
newuvmap.name = tmpuvmap_name
```

By setting `active_index = 0`, the call to `new()` duplicates the first UVMap, putting a duplicate of it at the end before deleting the first item.

This appears to give the same result as manually selecting the first item, clicking + to create a new UVMap then deleting the first item within blender.

Comment: Thank you a lot! This way works.
But it seems blender has a bug in renaming... Even if the object is removed I cannot name the new one with the same name. So that i must change your last code line:
    
    mesh.uv_textures[len(mesh.uv_textures) - 1].name = tmpuvmap_name

Comment: I reported this issue, but the dev said it's python limitation http://developer.blender.org/T37749

Answer (score 2):

Old thread but...This script works, I dont have time to make it as a AddOn, To use it, select the UvMap and then run this script

```
###################################################
#  UvMaps must be less than 8 because its use a
#  free map to reorder
#  Select the UvMap and Run this script (Alt + P)
#  I guess 8 Uvmaps is Blender's limit
#  Author: Victor Botelho (vlab22@gmail.com)
#
#  Steps this script does:
#  1. Duplicate de select UvMap (it goes to
#  the bottom uv index), delete the original
#  UvMap and rename the duplicated.
#
#  2. Duplicate the UvMap above the original
#  (already deleted) and does the same (delete
#  and rename)
#
#  3. Walks down each UvMap above "the original"
#  and does the same (duplicate, delete and rename)
###################################################

import bpy

uvTexts = bpy.context.object.data.uv_textures

acInx= bpy.context.object.data.uv_textures.active_index

if len(uvTexts) > 0 and len(uvTexts) < 8 and acInx > 0:

    uv = bpy.context.object.data.uv_textures.active
    uvActive = bpy.context.object.data.uv_textures.active_index
    print("uvActive: " + str(uvActive))
    uvName = uv.name

    uvTexts = bpy.context.object.data.uv_textures
    uvLoop = len(uvTexts) - uvActive - 1

    #Add a copy
    bpy.ops.mesh.uv_texture_add()

    bpy.context.object.data.uv_textures.active_index = uvActive

    #Remove old
    bpy.ops.mesh.uv_texture_remove()

    uvTexts = bpy.context.object.data.uv_textures

    bpy.context.object.data.uv_textures.active_index = len(uvTexts)-1

    uv = bpy.context.object.data.uv_textures.active
    uv.name = uvName

    #Add a copy
    bpy.context.object.data.uv_textures.active_index = uvActive - 1
    uvActive = bpy.context.object.data.uv_textures.active_index
    print("uvActive: " + str(uvActive))
    uv = bpy.context.object.data.uv_textures.active
    uvName = uv.name

    bpy.ops.mesh.uv_texture_add()

    bpy.context.object.data.uv_textures.active_index = uvActive

    #Remove Old
    bpy.ops.mesh.uv_texture_remove()

    uvTexts = bpy.context.object.data.uv_textures

    bpy.context.object.data.uv_textures.active_index = len(uvTexts)-1

    uv = bpy.context.object.data.uv_textures.active
    uv.name = uvName

    #Walk Down until
    limitInx = len(uvTexts)-2

    for i in range(0,uvLoop):
        print("for: " + str(i))
        bpy.context.object.data.uv_textures.active_index = uvActive
        uv = bpy.context.object.data.uv_textures.active
        uvName = uv.name

        bpy.ops.mesh.uv_texture_add()

        bpy.context.object.data.uv_textures.active_index = uvActive

        #Remove
        bpy.ops.mesh.uv_texture_remove()

        uvTexts = bpy.context.object.data.uv_textures

        bpy.context.object.data.uv_textures.active_index = len(uvTexts)-1

        uv = bpy.context.object.data.uv_textures.active
        uv.name = uvName

    bpy.context.object.data.uv_textures.active_index = uvActive
else:
    if (len(uvTexts) > 7):
        print("Maximum UvMaps permitted is 7")
```