Geometry nodes reorders UV layers when using Join node
When using the Join Node and a vertex group of geometry I duplicate and join, UV maps are reordered. How can I ensure the UV layers maintain the original order when using Join Geometry Node?
When modifiers are applied, you can see it is reordering the UV channels (below)
Left: Before Geometry Nodes are applied. Rights: After

Blend File:
https://blend-exchange.com/b/lrvnk4ZZ

Can you clarify what is dependent on UV Map order, as opposed to name?

@RobinBetts it matters which is the first because often you don't specify UV by name in shader

@MarkusvonBroady    ahh, OK.. but you can, if you want .. or stash the map as an attribute? .. and the default is the active UV map, not the first..

I actually knew it's not the first though honestly I don't know if it's the one with camera icon or the one with blue background :D But yeah those change too on the screenshot (that is, the first position remains chosen).

@RobinBetts To answer your first question, in my case I am exporting to a game engine, which depends on UVmap order and not name. UV layer index 0 should always be used for the texture maps, while the next UV index is often used for UV1. Because not all objects use geometry nodes, the export comes out with both objects with incorrect order and objects with correct order. So I don't believe using named attributes works in this case.

I'm now finding the uv layers are not reordered if the geometry nodes space is not open when the modifier is applied, but I would still like to better understand how this can be avoided.

Thanks @Zak.. that does look like undesirable inconsistent behaviour, for sure.. if not exactly a 'bug',  it's worthy of a report, IMO.  Let's hope for a getaround, for the time being.

Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/67266/35559

Reported as bug here: https://projects.blender.org/blender/blender/issues/123336

Right Cliock select considers this a bug https://blender.community/c/rightclickselect/lvX7/?sorting=hot
Meanwhile, Blender Developers are considering this a feature since attributes are not stores to keep a consistent order. https://projects.blender.org/blender/blender/issues/122994
